# Is there anyway that i can save my dataset into a file with .data extension?

Tags: java, r, file

I have a dataset which contains 3000 observations. It could be something like:

```
data.frame(A=letters,id=1:26 )
```

**I am looking for a way to save my dataset into a file with [.data extension](http://java-ml.sourceforge.net/content/databases)?**

An R solution is very good, but any other hint is very welcome.

I wish to use the data in Java in [this code](http://java-ml.sourceforge.net/content/classification-basics).

Comment: I guess that a simple `.csv` is good enough.

Comment: i am going to try it, but i am not sure if the library in `java` works with `.csv`, because the original sample is based on `.data`

Answer (score 0):

The .data format used by that library seems to be a tab separated values (tsv)
according to 
http://java-ml.sourceforge.net/api/0.1.0/net/sf/javaml/tools/data/FileHandler.html

> The format of the file should be as follows: One instance on each
>   line, all values of an entry on a single line, values should be
>   separated by a tab character or specified with the method and all
>   entries should have the same number of values.
>   Only class values are allowed to be non double. If a data set has no
>   labels, then all columns should be double values.

you should be able to use something like

```
write.table(mydata, file='test.data', quote=FALSE, sep='\t')
```